# Osgi java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when trying to retrieve a service from another bundle

Tags: java, osgi

So, let's see, I have three bundles: Provider *interface*, Provider *implementation* and Client.

Everything is running smoothly on Eclipse, but when I export the bundles and run em, the following error appears when I try to retrieve the Provider Service:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: provider/providerinterface/ProviderService
```

The interface is exporting his package, so there should be no errors with that. Alongside, Client is also importing the providerInterface package in its manifest.

The .jar of the Provider interface bundle does have the ProviderService class inside, so there are no error exporting either.

**Provider Interface's manifest**:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: IMA_Provider
Bundle-SymbolicName: IMA_Provider
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
Export-Package: provider.providerinterface
```

**Client's manifest:**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: MAClient
Bundle-SymbolicName: MA_Client
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
Import-Package: provider.providerinterface,
 org.osgi.framework;version="1.3.0",
 org.osgi.util.tracker;version="1.4.2"
```

Provider and Client are just symbolic names, the "Client" bundle imports and uses a lot of other classes from many other bundles with no errors whatsoever. Anyway, I'm getting stuck with this one, and I can't find any reason.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to solve this.

There were no issues with the **Manifest** files or the **build.properties**, this was a constructor problem.

The **MA_Provider** implementation was lacking a void constructor; Once I added this

```
public ProviderImpl(){}
```

on the **implementation** class of the ProviderInterface, the OSGi bundles were able to retrieve the service.

Answer (score 1):

Usually there is something wrong with the build.properties file, causing the bundles to miss the actual class files. This does not matter when running directly from Eclipse, but it does matter when you export the bundles using PDE.

Things to check:

- Are the classfiles really in the bundles? When checking the bundle, you should have at least at toplevel a provider/ folder and a META-INF/ folder
- the build.properties file should look something like:

  output.. = bin/
  source.. = src/
  bin.includes = META-INF/,.

Good luck, Frank

Comment: Hey Frank, honestly thanks for your help. Most of the times runtime problems outside eclipse are caused by these kind of errors related to manifest and build files, but this just wasn't the case, that's why I was stuck. Anyway, appreciated ; )